# A schema approach to load this Table as a RDF Model into Apache Jena Model

Tags: rdf, jena

I would like to create Linked data from this [sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evwXM.png). Here is a [sample structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w22Z3.png) I came up with and I need to load it into Jena. My approach is to obviously convert it into a CSV file and load it that way.

The challenge is in the code, since I need to preserve the semantics and relationships as shown in the structure. Superclass: Campain
Subclasses of Campain: Product A, Product B, etc. Each Product is of a certain type such as Cereal, Roots, etc and properties defined such as Property A, B,C, etc

I need how to model this into Jena

I am very new to Jena and creating **OntClass**. , defining types and adding properties and values. Thanks

Comment: So what exactly is the question now? I mean, make RDF from the CSV and then load it into Apache Jena. Creating RDF means making a data model first, i.e. you have to figure out what should be classes and what properties.

Comment: @UninformedUser thanks just edited the question with a sample structure I want

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking. If you create those classes and properties in Jena via Java code, how does this help to convert your CSV? Creating classes in Jena can be done via the method of an `OntModel`: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/

Comment: Nevertheless, you have to process your CSV file and create RDF triples. Or create OWL individuals and add attributes to them

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks for following up. I will figure out how to. All I need is a sample code with at least one Campain and Two products added into a Model. I believe that would give me a better idea on how to go about loading the CSV data and dinamically creating everything

Comment: the link I added shows how to use the Ontology API of Jena. It shows how to create classes, individuals and add properties to individuals. That's basically all you need I think.

Comment: still struggling to create exactly as the structure shows